# From mdadm raid to LVM (raid or mirror) decisions and how to monitor

Tags: lvm, partition, mdadm, diskmanagement, mirroring

We are migrating some server from linux raids (0 and 1) to LVM with stripe or mirrors.
At the moment our systems are mainly configured something like

```
| /tmp - /home - /others 
|------------------------
| LVM group
|------------------------
| mdadm Linux Raid 1
|------------------------
| sda1 - sdb1
```

We know mdadm is very solid but LVM provides great flexibility in order to move live partitions from one disk to other, replace one of the disks and specially extending or reducing partitions.

Our main concern is regarding how to implement it and also how to replace the tools provided by mdadm in order to monitor the raid status, alerts and percentage of reconstruction if one disk is replaced. i understand lvs is the only tool for that but requires manual processing alerts based on grepping the result.

**lvcreate --type raid1' vs 'lvcreate -m 1'**

Completely uncertain too regarding wether we should use the relatively newer raid within LVM vs the more established mirror and stripe options of LVM
I've found [some articles about it](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/220n8w/whats_the_difference_between_lvcreate_type_raid1/) but they still go 6 years back and still uncertained if we should do that move and if we do if we should use mirrors or raid LV partitions.

Comment: mdraid works perfectly well, you can run regular LVM volumes on top of it and still do stuff like live-migrate them, so I don't see the advantage to switching. Not to mention Stratis is on the horizon and will likely replace both LVM and mdraid in functionality.

Comment: reason being we are suddenly having odd issues with a kernel with raid10+lvm on top and mainly as any change in the structure or sizes of the underlaying mdadm raids is a nightmare compared to live migrating it with lvm